# Wicket 7 Link/Label error when using inheritance

Tags: wicket

With Wicket 7, I am working on an app that uses a base page as a template for other pages to extend.

On the base page, I want to have a label and a link that changes depending on whether the user is authenticated or not.

Here's my BasePage.html:

```
<div wicket:id="chromeMenu">foo</div>
    <div>
        <h2 wicket:id="userGreeting"></h2>
        <h2><a href="#" wicket:id="loginLink"><span wicket:id="loginLabel"></span></a> </h2>
    </div>
<wicket:child/>
```

and the BasePage.java:

```
public BasePage() {
    super();

    add(new ChromeDropDownMenu("chromeMenu", buildMenu()));

    add(new Label("pageTitle", new StringResourceModel("page.title", this, null)));

    if(BasicAuthenticatedSession.get().isSignedIn()) {
        // Do stuff here
    } else {
        add(new Label("userGreeting", "Hello Visitor"));
        add(new Link("loginLink") {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
            }
        });
        add(new Label("loginLabel","Test"));
    }
}
```

HomePage extends BasePage.

HomePage.html

```
<wicket:extend/>
```

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HomePage() {
        super();

        setPageTitle(new StringResourceModel("page.title", this, new Model<Serializable>("Admin")));

        add(new Label("version", getApplication().getFrameworkSettings().getVersion()));

    }
}
```

HomePage is the class returned by the Wicket application.

When I try to load HomePage, I get the following error:

```
Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'loginLabel' in [Link [Component id = loginLink]]
    Expected: 'loginLink:loginLabel'.
    Found with similar names: 'loginLabel'
```

It points to the **<a><span/></a>** structure from BasePage.html as the root of the problem.

I've tried a few ways to work around this, but without success. I thought maybe an **add(Link).add(Label)** might be needed, but that didn't work either.

Any thoughts out there on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all.

> Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'loginLabel' in [Link
>   [Component id = loginLink]]
>       Expected: 'loginLink:loginLabel'.
>       Found with similar names: 'loginLabel'

Wicket is expecting the same component hierarchy in your Java code as you've written in the HTML. In BasePage.html you have:

```
<h2><a href="#" wicket:id="loginLink"><span wicket:id="loginLabel"></span></a> </h2>
```

In the BasePage.java code you need to add loginLabel as a child of loginLink component.

```
    Link loginLink = new Link("loginLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
        }
    };
    add(loginLink);
    loginLink.add(new Label("loginLabel", "Test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at

```
add(new Link("loginLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
        }
    });
    add(new Label("loginLabel","Test"));
```

The Link should be the parent of the Label:

```
link = new Link("loginLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        setResponsePage(LoginPage.class);
    }
};
link.add(new Label("loginLabel","Test"));
add(link);
```

Few extra notes:

- better use BookmarkablePageLink if setResponsePage() is the only thing you need in `onClick()`
- use AbstractLink#setBody(IModel label) instead of Link+Label